# Why Spark streaming creates batches with 0 events?

Tags: apache-spark

Spark streaming keeps on creating batches with 0 events and queues them to be processed in next job iteration. But is it really necessary to queue batches which have nothing to be processed or is there something hidden going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is working as intended because your job could still produce output even in the absence of data (which can also happen after filtering your data).

For example you might write some record to the database that indicates that there's no data available at a given timestamp.

```
stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  if (rdd.isEmpty)  // write "empty" record to db
  else // write data to db
}
```